# Run an EXE file from MATLAB 64bit (Windows 8.1 64Bits)

Tags: matlab, 64-bit

I want to run an EXE file named "LBRM.EXE" by MATLAB.
I try:

```
dos('lbrm.exe')
```

and I get error:

> 'lbrm.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
>   operable program or batch file.

Exactly the same code works fine in 32bit MATLAB.

mesh -setup did not help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the EXE in your environmental variables in Windows or to move to the directory of the EXE file.
To move to the directory of the EXE file, use CD('EXE file folder') then you can execute your file by using the system command. `system('lbrm.exe')`

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears you're not returning any arguments from the call, you could see if you have better luck with the [bang operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/run-external-commands-scripts-and-programs.html):

```
!lbrm.exe
```